# Add delay between retries in istio

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, servicemesh

I installed istio v1.20.1 on my minicube.
Also I have a *go-client* service that makes a request to *go-server*.
If *go-server* returns code 425, I need to retry request after N seconds taken from the retry-after header

I'm trying to do this through a virtual-service, and an envoy-filter that will patch it.

So I have a virtual-service for *go-server*:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: go-server-virtual-service
  labels:
    app: go-server
spec:
  hosts:
    - go-server-service
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: go-server-service
      retries:
        attempts: 4
        perTryTimeout: 2s
        retryOn: "425"
```

and envoy-filter for *go-client*:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: retry-after-envoy-filter
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: go-client
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: "go-server-service:8001"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          route:
            retry_policy:
              rate_limited_retry_back_off:
                reset_headers:
                  - name: retry-after
                max_interval: "3s"
```

But all repeated requests are executed instantly, without any delays.

I found a similar problem here, but this also did not help to add any delay: [override-istio-retry-back-off-interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434510/override-istio-retry-back-off-interval)

Do you have any ideas what to check or why the delay is not working?

Comment: does your response contains the header "Retry-After" set?  so that the envoy to perform retry after the interval